# FPDI & TCPDF problems?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdi

Im having a rather odd problem getting FPDI & TTCPDF php classes to work together.

FPDI: http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/

TCPDF: http://www.tcpdf.org/

From reading around and even looking at some of the examples given, these should work together NO PROBLEM...

however.. I am getting some conflicts (or something)

This link shows a rather simple & straight forward way to using BOTH the TPDF and TCPDF classes together:

[setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/](http://setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/)

I am running this/testing this LOCALLY using WAMP.. and PHP version 5.4.12

```
<?php
// just require TCPDF instead of FPDF
//require_once 'fpdf/fpdf.php'; //old
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');

class PDF extends FPDI{
}
// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("SRS_blank.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 210mm (width of A4)
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 210, 297);

// now write some text above the imported page

//position table at bottom
$pdf->SetXY(0, 200);
//set table font
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
//set table color
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
//table html
$html = '<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td width="70" rowspan="6">Company Name</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td rowspan="6"><img src="images/SRS_logo.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>City/State/Zip</td>
        <td>phone/fax</td>
        <td>email</td>
        <td>URL</td>
    </tr>
</table>';
// output the HTML table to pdf overlay
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Here are the errors I am now getting when trying to use TCPDF (which has much more robust options for displaying content)

> Strict standards: Declaration of FPDF::_putstream() should be compatible with TCPDF::_putstream($s, $n = 0) in C:\wamp\www\projects\PDF_generation\FPDI\fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php on line 167

and this:

> Strict standards: Declaration of FPDF_TPL::SetFont() should be compatible with TCPDF::SetFont($family, $style = '', $size = NULL, $fontfile = '', $subset = 'default', $out = true) in C:\wamp\www\projects\PDF_generation\FPDI\fpdf_tpl.php on line 460

I am stuck on HOW I get a decent dev environment to test and work with these two classes?

Any ideas?  all suggestions appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: Did you tried with: ini_set('display_errors', '0');   and 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Comment: I will..but not sure HOW?  How do I implement that into my current set-up? Is this something I need to do in my php.ini file?

Comment: Yoa can insert those two lines at the beggining of your php script.

Comment: That seemed to work in helping surpress those warning messages.. thanks!!!

Comment: No problem, i'm here to help ;)

Answer (score 7):

when overloading function need specify all params (also with default value)

In file `fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php` at line 31 set declaration of function

```
function _putstream($s) {
```

on

```
function _putstream($s, $n=0) {
```

AND in `file fpdf_tpl.php` at line 275 set declaration of function

```
public function SetFont($family, $style = '', $size = 0) {
```

on

```
public function SetFont($family, $style = '', $size = 0, $fontfile = '', $subset = 'default', $out = true) {
```

Comment: Great answer dear friend. This answer must be selected as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of the latest version of both FPDI and TCPDF, this strict warning should not be occurring any longer.  I don't know which version of FPDI is when they finally started overloading TCPDF's functions correctly, but it appears that the following mixes of PHP, FPDI, and TCPDF do not generate these warnings anymore...

**PHP Version: 5.5.10**

**FPDI Version: 1.5.2**  - http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/

**TCPDF Version: 6.0.089** - http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/

Comment: holy cow..  3+ (almost 4) years old post by now.. and still need to put your fingers in it and tweak/edit...etc..etc.  (great job)  (eye roll)